# Existe algo que funcione como um "Firebug" para Android?

Tags: android, app, senhas, whatsapp

Eu preciso recuperar a minha senha do WhatsApp para utilizar a WhatsAPI. Já tentei tudo o que foi oferecido por ela (MissVenom, WART, Engenharia reversa [ não consegui ], efetuar o cadastro através da própria API [ também sem sucesso ], e até coisas que nem fazia sentido eu tentar, rsrs).

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma espécie de "Firebug" para requisições ANDROID, com isso eu pretendo ver quais servidores estão sendo chamados e o que está sendo passado pra eles (imagino que no cadastro é senha é enviada do aparelho para o servidor do WhatsApp, assim eu conseguiria ver minha senha e utilizar a API).

Estou aberto a outras soluções.
Desde já, obrigado.

[WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI)

Comment: Ta mas você acha que nas requisições do WhatsApp, eles enviam a senha em `text/plain`? Limpinha, sem criptografia nada? Não conheço nada da API, mas acho que não são tão amadores a esse ponto, e se fizessem, já nem existiriam mais. Pois já teriam explorado esse vulnerabilidade. Acredito que nenhuma requisição deles deve ir pela rede sem criptografia. Mas se quiser tentar, faça de seu computador um roteador, e bote o [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) a rodar e rastreie todos os pacotes. E boa sorte. hehe

Comment: Caso seu android tenha permissão root, use este aplicativo: [WhatsPwd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.maxters.droid.xpsd.whatsapp.pwd&hl=pt_BR), comigo funciona perfeitamente! @Mukotoshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não vou explicar passo a passo porque isso leva um certo tempo, mas vou te apresentar as ferramentas.

A primeira ferramenta que posso te indiciar é o **Charles Web Debugging Proxy**. Ele nada mais é do que um programa que você instala no seu computador permitindo criar um proxy para debugar requisições HTTP(s). Para utilizar em conjunto com Android você deve ativar o proxy e ele vai te informar um IP do proxy a ser configurado na conexão WiFi do Android, por isso ambos devem estar na mesma rede.

Para debug dos processos do Android você pode utilizar o **Android Debug Bridge** (adb) que vem junto com SDK. Você pode criar filtros para processos em específicos de forma fácil.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o Firebug lite

https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Para Chrome

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Quase isso, infelizmente o "Remote Debugging" do Chrome parece só debuggar WebView, eu precisava de algo que debuggasse tudo (ou pelo menos as requisições à servidores)